# 2x1 weather forecast widget for Android

Tags: gratis, android, weather

On my Android home I have just 2x1 of space left and would like to use it to show weather forecast.

2x1 is not big, but it could at least show a sun/rain/snow icon and temperature for today and tomorrow. Maybe something like this:

[image: Ideal weather forecast 2x1 widget]

Must be 2x1, must show forecast.
Must be free, wonderful if open source.

---

I have tried most of the Google Play top results, none of them fit the requirements:

[Weatherzone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=au.com.weatherzone.android.weatherzonefreeapp) does not seem to show any forecast:

[image: Weatherzone]

[The Weather Channel](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.weather.Weather) only shows the current weather. Forecast widgets are at least 4x2:

[image: The Weather Channel]

[Weather & Clock Widget Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devexpert.weather) only shows the current weather. Forecast widgets are at least 4x1:

[image: Weather & Clock Widget Android]

Same for [WeatherBug](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aws.android):

[image: WeatherBug]

Same again for [Weather 360, forecast &widgets](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sixthsolution.weather360) and [The Weather Network](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pelmorex.WeatherEyeAndroid).

[Weather Forecast](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blogspot.androidinspain) does not recognize "Tokyo, Japan".

Comment: You could install an app which will show the weather forecast in your notification bar.  I use the open-source ["Weather notification"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.gelin.android.weather.notification&hl=en) app by Denis Nelubin, plus his ["Bigger text"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.gelin.android.weather.notification.skin.biggertext&hl=en) skin.

Comment: Or you could post a separate question and ask whether or not it's possible to shrink all your widgets and icons 10% smaller. You might have to squint in order to read the shrunk text; but you could fit more widgets onscreen. (Who knows: on a rooted phone, maybe there even exists some way to change your phone's DPI setting on a per-app basis. Maybe using Tasker or whatnot.)

Answer (score 1):

The [Yahoo! Japan weather app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.yahoo.android.weather.type1) has exactly that:

[image]

It is free, but not open source.

Warning: It is in Japanese.